Soft body disappear in Animation
I have a problem regarding a soft body-cloth interaction. I want to create an animation of a cube falling onto a cloth and both objects reacting accordingly, with different reaction depending on the weight of the cube. When I start the animation, if I put 1 kg as the weight of the cube the cube disappears, whereas if I make the cube heavier (e.g. 10 kg), the animation works. Does anyone know why this happens?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried to recreate a simple test according to your description, but things just worked fine with default values. Honestly you are not providing many details, so I would just list what I've done and you could double-check what is going on.
The followings are done in Blender 4.2.


Create a plane, scale it up in Edit Mode (Simulation things always get weird when scaling in object mode without applying the scale) and subdivide it for 10 times; Add a subdivision modifier and switch to Simple with level 2;
Assign four corner vertexes of the plane to a pin group; In the physics tab add Cloth and Collision; In the shape tab of the Cloth settings set the pin group;
Create a cube, move it above the plane and simply add Collision and Soft-body in the physics tab(I assume that you may want this cube as soft body? Because you are talking about soft body-cloth interaction); Uncheck the Goal option so that the cube may fall when hit play;
Now, as I don't know if there are some other settings that you may want, I just simply hit play and the animation went smoothly. I tried to change the cube's weight for several different values, nothing went wrong, except that if the weight went too heavy the cube just cracked itself, but it is not about the disappearance of animation.


I think it is working fine with default settings, so I suppose that it might be either you are making some advanced settings that make a difference, or that you are missing some necessary steps as I have shown you above. Sorry if this did not help you, but anyway there is too little information according to your description. Better share your .blend file, or at least state your project configurations with some screen shots, so that people can help you with enough knowledge about your question.

Thank you for your answer!
Yes, by leaving all settings as default the animation works, but I played with a lot of settings to get an animation as realistic as possible. It works fine for weights > 3Kg, but if I go under the cube just disappears, does this mean that the settings can make the object completely disappear just by changing the weight instead of just changing the interaction?
